# Django runserver through Vagrant without ssh

Tags: django, vagrant, puppet

I'm trying to configure a Vagrant box so it's very simple to use by some non developers.

This Vagrant contains a Django app that I'd like to start in dev env without the need of doing

```
host $ vagrant up
host $ vagrant ssh
guest $ cd app; python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Ideally I'd like `vagrant up` to do this job automatically or maybe something like

```
host $ vagrant exec start-django
```

I found [someone suggesting](http://zacharyflower.com/2014/01/21/running-django-automatically-in-vagrant-using-puppet/) this piece of Puppet

```rb
exec { "start-django":
    command => "/bin/su -c 'cd /vagrant ; /usr/bin/screen -S runserver -d -m
                /usr/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000' vagrant",
    require => Package["screen"]
}
```

But I don't understand how to use it and if it's a good way to do it.

So question: **How can I run my django app without having to ssh into the VM ?**

---

Puppet is my provisioner here

Comment: Why don't you set it up to use an actual server inside the VM? eg configure Apache/mod_wsgi or gunicorn/nginx? Then it could start on vagrant up.

Comment: As I'm also developing with this box, I'd like to keep the flexibility of the devserver. By "non developers" I actually meant non Django dev to which I'd like to show the simplicity of Django :) Do you think it's a bad idea to run the devserver from outside the VM ?